# Azure VM restart without notice

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

The azure VM restart automatically without notice. I have setup availability set for web servers, but the staging and sql servers are on individual VMs. Will Microsoft notify on service healing and host updates? If so, how do we set it up? I am the admin, and I did not receive any notification.

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault; it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no automatic notification of service healing. If you require this, you'll need to set up monitoring of the individual VMs yourself.

Comment: Could you provide information or point to a resource on how to do this?

Comment: I received a few emails from MS notifying me of VM (host) updates. But this shouldn't be any problem because you have the availability set, MS won't upgrade both VM's at the same time.

Comment: I wouldn't say "shouldn't be any problem", because depending on the workload, your first VM may not be fully operational by the time the second is taken down. A key example of this is a relational database server. While the first VM may be up, SQL may still be starting and reaching quorum (in the case of a SQL replica set). So "any problem" should be treated as a relative term. As for how to do this, it depends largely on the application but the simplest option I usually suggest is something actively monitoring for an open endpoint on the VM and then sending a notification